# Powershell avoid adding duplicate firewall rules windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell

I created the following script,
but for some reason it continues creating the rules every time I execute the script,

```
$RULENAME1 = 'Domain Controllers'
$Rule = netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="$RULENAME1" $nul

if ($RULENAME1 -eq $Rule) {

echo "Rule "$RULENAME1" already exist."
echo "Hey, you already got a out rule by that name, you cannot put another one in!"

} else {
echo Rule "$RULENAME1" not exist. Creating...
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="$RULENAME1"  dir=in action=allow remoteip=10.10.10.10
}
```

Could you guys help on what I'm missing here?

EDIT: 
the solution is to modify the `IF` statement in this

```
"$Rule" -notmatch "No rules match"
```

Comment: `$rule` contains the full definition of the rule. It will certainly not be identical to the name... Pipe the output `| out-null` and check `$lastexitcode`. If there was no rule by that name, `netsh` will return `1`, otherwise `0`. (Of course, it will also return `1` if anything else went wrong.)

Comment: tried this but doesn't work
`$Rule = netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="$RULENAME1" | out-nul

if ($lastexitcode -eq 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to replace `$RULENAME1 -eq $Rule` with something like:

```
"$Rule" -notmatch "No rules match"
```

inside your if statement, wrap `$Rule` with `"`s to stop `-notmatch` treating it as an array.

Comment: It doesn't work, it say that the rule already exists

Rule Domain Controllers Already exists, you cannot put another one in!